# ORA-1033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am stuck with a little Oracle problem. My PC was shut down improperly after my graphics card freaked out, which caused Oracle 11g Express to not properly close down. This means that I get the above error when I try to connect. My PC has been on for 3 hours, and I still get the error, so it is safe to assume that there's something wrong.

The usual way of remedying the problem is to use the following sequence of commands from the command line:

```
sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect / as sysdba
SQL> shutdown abort
SQL> startup nomount
SQL> alter database mount;
SQL> alter database open;
```

However, when I give the shutdown command, I get the error

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

So now, I can't mount my db. ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question needs a proper solution. I got a similar issue due to graphics card failure.

Comment: If you find one, post it here and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well sadly in my case I had to reinstall oracle to make things work. Configuring a new SID even did not work. So I dont know about the solution but best you can do to "create restore points" of your database to quick fix such issues in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not necessary or even possible in all cases, but I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Oracle because I get paid per hour and I'd rather spend that time producing code than wrestling with Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Open the Start menu --> All Programs
2. Open folder *"Oracle Database 11g Express Edition"*
3. Choose *"Start Database"*
4. Wait until you get *"C:\Windows\system32"*
5. Open *"Run SQL Command Line"* and connect to your database

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your listener service is not running.
You can check this by openening the services screen by (in Win7) searching for "services". In the list you should find an Oracle Listener service with status Started.

Comment: I don't believe you need the listener running if you are connecting directly (such as using `/ as sysdba`).

Comment: All the oracle services on my machine are running.